# How do I simulate a webcam?

Tags: webcam

I just can't... v4l2loopback just doesn't get detected. (Simply does nothing even when I pipe all the video to /dev/video0 using ffmpeg). I can't join any web meetings because my webcam is broken. Any help?

Comment: By a new one. When hardware is broken, then you need a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Since [OBS Studio 26.1](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/releases/tag/26.1.0), released on 14 December 2020, virtual camera support is available on Linux without the need of external plugins.

Install OBS Studio normally with your preferred method, both `snap`, and `apt` are fine.

Then you must install [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) kernel module. You can follow the instructions starting from [#build](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback#build) to [#install](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback#install).

```bash
(
  cd $(mktemp -d)
  git clone https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git
  cd v4l2loopback
  make
  sudo make install
  sudo depmod -a
)
```

Once v4l2loopback is installed, launch OBS Studio (or restart if you already had it open) and it will detect the new kernel module and show the button to enable the virtual camera.

#### Before OBS Studio 26.1

This was the old answer, but I will keep this here for individuals that may be stuck on an outdated version of OBS Studio.

You can do so with [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio)) on Linux by using the [OBS Virtualcam](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.949/) plugin.

> #### Does this plugin support other platforms?
>
> For Linux, you can use the [Video4Linux sink plugin](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink) for OBS Studio. Directions on how to configure it are available from that link.way to provide a similar plugin for macOS, but there is no ETA.

Comment: It says the supported operating system is Windows, would it work if I just build it myself?

Comment: If you scroll down a bit, it has an alternative build which is for Linux, which is also linked in this post. (You want to click "Video4Linux sink plugin".)

Comment: Thanks, however, it fails to install libOBS. Is there a prebuilt version available?

Comment: Got that all sorted out, but now Tools > V4L2 Video Output doesn't exist. The one on the control thing does something but doesn't really get detected by anything.

Comment: I've just attempted to set this up myself, and learned that OBS Studio 26.1 has native support for virtual cameras on Linux, you just have to install the v4l2loopback kernel module. See my updated answer.

Comment: It looks like the OBS team pulled the code from the obs-v4l2sink plugin for the native integration. https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink/issues/56#issuecomment-753191690

Comment: That camera doesn't get detected by anything though.

Comment: I've just tested this myself, both in local applications like Discord, and on websites via Firefox. It should get detected correctly if setup.

Comment: It enables, but it doesn't even get detected by Cheese.